# Trying to understand how pl sql stored proc work and why my results differ

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a simple stored proc...

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE GET_PERSON (aName VARCHAR2, p_data OUT sys_refcursor)
IS
BEGIN
   OPEN p_data FOR SELECT * FROM people_table WHERE firstname = aName;
END;
```

However when I execute the stored proc it returns all of the records.

```
DECLARE 
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_1   number;
  v_2   VARCHAR2(50);
  v_3   VARCHAR2(200);
  v_4   VARCHAR2(50);
  v_5   VARCHAR2(50);
  v_6   VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  GET_PERSON ('aaa@bbb.com', v_cur);

  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur INTO v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_2 || ' ' || v_3);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_cur;
END;
```

If I run the simple statement

```
SELECT * FROM people_table WHERE firstname = 'aaa@bbb.com';
```

It correctly returns one record.

Why is the stored proc not behaving the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue..

My issue was name collision.   When I altered the code above is when I noticed the issue.  I originally has WHERE fistname = firstName.  Once I changed the parameter to p_firstName as was well.